# how to parse $scope to an angular js object?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

thanks for your quick response.the scenario am trying to cover is as follows:-

1) there will be a json file, which will contain the entire formly template (the code I provided ).
2) there will be javascript file that will read the template from json file and assign to "vm.formFields" .

the problem that I am facing is all the scope variables within the function (validation) and the model is being treated as a string rather then the scope variable. Is there a  way we can define model variables and function variable in the formly template within the json file that will get bound to the scope.

the idea is we want to pass different formly templates(dynamically based on certain conditions) to render different elements without changing the angular partial and javascript file

Here is the code(which right in the js file):-

```
vm.formFields = [
                                {
                                    className : "reg-custom-row"
                                },
                                {
                                    className : "add-prod-col-4",
                                    key : 'feild1',
                                    type : 'input',
                                    model : $scope.addFEILDTemplate.FANVO[0],
                                    templateOptions : {
                                        label : 'Feild1',
                                        onKeyup : function($viewValue,
                                                $modelValue, scope) {
                                            $scope.isNumericInput(
                                                    $viewValue, 0);
                                        },
                                        required : true,
                                        placeholder : 'Feild1'
                                    }
                                },
                                {

                                    className : "add-prod-col-8 addmargin",
                                    key : 'feild2',
                                    type : 'input',
                                    model : $scope.addFANTemplate.FANVO[0],
                                    templateOptions : {
                                        label : 'feild2',
                                        required : true,
                                        onKeyup : function($viewValue,
                                                $modelValue, scope) {
                                            $scope.isAlphaNumeric(
                                                    $viewValue, 0);
                                        },
                                        placeholder : 'feild2'
                                    }
                                }

                        ];
```

Comment: Can you please add any code, to make a better impression ?

Comment: $scope is already an AngularJS object. What do you want exactly?

Comment: Add your code it looks like you're not injecting your dependencies correctly.

Comment: Please have a look at Dependency Injection in AngularJS: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: If you need help with angular-formly, the best way to get it is by following the instructions here: http://help.angular-formly.com